# Place two videos side by side using ffmpeg?and download it as one file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

I have two video files, which I want to play side by side and download them later. I used  ***FFMPEG*** to merge them as one:

```cs
protected void combinetwovideo()
{
    string strParam;
    string Path_FFMPEG = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FFMpegPath"]));
    string apppath=HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
    //Merging two videos               
    String video1=apppath+"\\recordings\\client2019-08-03 02_23_59";
    String video2 =apppath+"\\userrecord\\User2019-08-03 02_24_00";
    String strResult =apppath+"\\RESULT\\";
    strParam = string.Format("-i ('" + video1 + "') -i ('" + video2 + "') -filter_complex \'[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' /-map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.mp4");
    process(Path_FFMPEG, strParam);
}
```

```cs
 public void process(string Path_FFMPEG, string strParam)
 {
    try
    {
        Process ffmpeg = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo ffmpeg_StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path_FFMPEG, strParam);
        ffmpeg_StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ffmpeg_StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        ffmpeg_StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo = ffmpeg_StartInfo;
        ffmpeg_StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ffmpeg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        ffmpeg.Start();
        ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
        ffmpeg.Close();
        ffmpeg.Dispose();
        ffmpeg = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

But this method outputs nothing and does not throw any errors. I'm confused about the `strParam` query. Did I write it wrong or am I missing something. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: The string parameter is everything that is on the command line except the first parameter which is the program name.  I would check Task Manager while application is running and see if the process is running or terminating.  It is possible the application is running but the window is not showing.

Comment: @jdweng couldn't track anything! not showing the process is running!!!

Comment: Then the process is not starting or terminating quickly.  I would create a bat file and run from cmd.exe to see if an error is returned.  May be in from cmd.exe set Path = "" to simulate same condition as in c#.  Using the process class the environmental variable are empty.  If the application is using any environmental variable that could be the reason for app not working.